# Jwplayer I cant play vast tags in my desktop

Tags: javascript, jwplayer6

Was trying to implement vast tag in my JWplayer. Have checked the vast tag in online validator its workign fine. But I cant able to view the ads in my video. Have given the code please help me..

Have I missed anything. or Is I need to buy any licence to play ad tags in Jwplayer.

```
  jwplayer("player").setup({

       file: "rtmp://stream.metamorphosis.tv:1935/videos/_definst_/mp4:octv.mp4",
       width:"100%",
       aspectratio: "4:3",
       image:     "http://cdn.metamorphosis.tv/osp/hls/OCTVNewsWaterfrontRestaurantHyattRegencyTrinidad/poster/poster.jpg",
       primary: 'flash',
       advertising: {
            client: "vast",
            tag: "http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast2RegularLinear.xml"
        }
   });
```

Comment: Hi is i need to bye any licence to play ad tags.